# Using git and xcode, some folders are not commited

Tags: xcode, git

I'm new to git and just started using bitbucket in xcode.

Is it normal that some folders are not commited?

Folders like: 
resources, libs, framework, supporting files, products - are missing when I view the folders in bitbucket site.

Thanks...

Answer (score 3):

Please check your `.gitignore` file, maybe it has that folders listed there